# Problem: No drawable files from Resource folder seen on ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I searched for this question and couldnt find any answers. I started coding 2 days ago on Android Studio (Java). So I'm a super beginner.
Every youtube video (up to date) or tutorial that I watch, they copy an image to the drawable folder inside the Res folder and when they drag an ImageView to the layout a pop up screen appears, which contains all the images and resources, meaning the picture they added is there on the project ready to be added as the image source of the ImageView.
Example:
[This tutorial adding a horse.jpg that can be seen already on the drawable folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amLQv.png)

Meanwhile my Android Studio also has a beginner-gym-routine.jpg file on the drawable folder (as also can be seen on the left side) but NOTHING appears on the pop up screen when I drop an ImageView (Searched everywhere).
Example:
[My Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDtQL.png)

I dont understand what is going wrong or what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when your image has special characters in it.

Like your image `beginner-gym-routine.jpg` contains "**-**" which is causing this.

You just **rename** your image and **remove** the dashes.

Hope it works out :-)